# choose different colors in matlab plots

Tags: matlab

This is my plot code. The problem is that two lines in my plot have same colors, I need one special for each line in the plot (totally 4 lines).

```
for i=1:nFolderContents;
    [~, data] = hdrload(folderContents(i,:));
    if size(folderContents(i,:),2)<size(folderContents,2);
        temp=folderContents(i,6:9);
    else
       temp=folderContents(i,6:7);
    end
    temp1(i)=strread(temp);
    w=2*pi*(data([35 51 68 101],1));
    permfreespace=8.854e-12;
    perm=data([36 52 69 101],3);
    cond=perm.*w.*permfreespace;
    conds([36 52 69 101],i)=cond;
    hold on

end


figure(4);plot(temp1,conds);
gcf=figure(4);
set(gcf,'Position', [0 0 295 245]);
xlabel('Temperature [\circC]'), ylabel ('Conductivity [s/m]');
title('Different frequencies');
legend('1.02 GHz','1.50 GHz','2.01 GHz','3 GHz');
axis([20 52 0 4]);
box on
```

Comment: how is this different from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473386/i-need-different-colors-in-my-matlab-plot ?

Comment: I did not get any answer there :(

Comment: You must not post duplicate questions on SO. See this: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search on 'Matlab plot colors' gives this as the second link:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

This has many examples with plots with different colors. It feels like you did not do any research before posting your question.

Comment: may be you didnt understod my problem.

Comment: If so, I also didn't understand. Can you clarify what you've asked that doesn't have an answer in this link...?

Answer (score 0):

Well do something like this using the [hold function](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/hold.html):

```
mycolors=['m','k','y','r'];
figure();
for i =1:4;
    p=plot(temp[i],conds);
    set(p,'Color',mycolors[i],'LineWidth',2)

    xlabel('Temperature [\circC]'), ylabel ('Conductivity [s/m]');
    title('Different frequencies');
    legend('1.02 GHz','1.50 GHz','2.01 GHz','3 GHz');
    hold all;
```